# How to extract the version string defined on the fist line of a file in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I want to extract version string which is defined in the first line of the file.

**file.txt**

```
version="11.22.33" project="foo"
this is a foo project with version "11.22.33" written in some language of version "44.55.66"
```

I would like to have a command which would only read the first line of the file and extract `11.22.33` from it and stop.

I tried `variable_str=$(sed -rn "0,/<pattern_for_version>/p")` but this returns the whole line and not only the matched pattern.

Comment: You said in comments below that it might have double of single quotes. Will there ever be a case where it might have none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F\" '{print $2; exit}' file
11.22.33
```

Comment: I was under the impression he wanted the quotes.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I don't want quotes (they could be single or double quotes).

Comment: Please update the question with that info - will update my answer as well. ;)

Answer (score 5):

why spawn another process?

```
$: IFS="$IFS=" read x version x < file.txt
$: echo "$version"
"11.22.33"
```

IFS is the internal field separator list, which by default includes spaces, tabs, & newlines. If you add `=` then a single read against the file will split the first line into as many fields as you have asked for.

> version "11.22.33" project="foo"

It will assign these to the vars provided, so give it places to put the initial field you don't want and everything behind the field you do want, and it will drop the version value cleanly into where you do want it.

It will leave everything unparsed in the final field if you don't provide enough -

```
$: echo $x
project="foo"
```

If you wanted to strip the quotes, add `"` to IFS as well, and give a place for the empty field that will result. To strip single quotes, add those, etc...

```
$: IFS="$IFS='\"" read x x version x < file.txt
$: echo "$version"
11.22.33
```

Comment: If there's a chance that it might have *no* quotes - `awk -F "[= '\"]" '{ if ($3 ~ /[0-9.]+/) print $3; else print $2; exit}' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
awk -F "[= ]" 'NR==1 {gsub(/\"/,"",$2);print $2}' file.txt
```

`NR` is the number of row and `-F` indicates the fields separator, in this case equal and whitespace. If you want the quotation marks

```
awk -F "[= ]" 'NR==1 {print $2}' file.txt
```

Comment: or `awk -F '"' 'NR==1 {print $2}' file.txt`

Comment: Quick question, just because I'm curious. Is `awk` smart enough to exit after it has parsed the only row that could match its criteria, or will it grind through reading all the rest of the rows in the file and checking the line numbers? Usually won't matter, but it is technically possible that the file could have a few million rows.... Easy enough to solve with an `exit` the way [Ed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) did in his answer, which doesn't even require a comparison against the line number as long as you always want the first row. :)

Comment: @PaulHodges: Normally awk runs through the whole file. But you can prevent this: `awk -F '"' 'NR==1 {print $2; exit}' file.txt`

Comment: Then you don't need the `NR==1`. ;)

Comment: I like passing a character class for the delimiters, though. Since the OP said he doesn't want to quotes, I'd mix that with Ed's solution. `awk -F "['\"]" '{print $2; exit}' file.txt`

Comment: @PaulHodges: :) Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to first `head` the first line and second to extract the pattern

```
head -1 file.txt | sed 's#.*version=\(\"[^"]*\"\).*#\1#'
```

You use `sed`'s search and substitute:
The parantheses (which have to be escaped) record the wanted pattern (a double quote, everything but a double quote, a double quote). The replacement is just the recorded pattern (`\1`).

Comment: head makes you cope with only one line

Comment: You can use `q` command of sed to do that, like: `1s/foo/bar/;q`.